# Existence of Admissible Maps

Tags: algebraic-topology

Following Whitehead's notation, given a fibration $p\colon E\to B$ with fibres $F$, let $u\colon [0,1]\to B$ any path, and let $F_0 ,F_1$ be the fibres of the fibration over the starting and end points of $u$. Then we say a continuous map $h\colon F_1\to F_0$ $u_t$-**admissible** if $h$ is homotopic as a map to $E$ to $\mathrm{id}_1\colon F_1\to F_1\subseteq E$ such that the homotopy $H\colon I\times F_1\to E$ satisfies $p\circ H(t,x)=u(t)$. My question is: for any $0$-connected space $B$ and a fibration $E\to B$, is there always exists such a $u_t$-admissible map for all path $u$? Or are there conditions for this to hold?(I would expect it's more general than a differetiable fibre bundle, which is trivial because of the existence of connections)

This would then tells us that a fibration corresponds to a contravariant functor from the fundamental groupoid $\Pi_1 (B)$ to the category $\mathsf{hTop}$ with objects topological spaces and morphisms homotopy classes of continuous maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fibrations are defined via the homotopy lifting property. Consider the following commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
F_1 @>{j_1}>> E \\
@V{i_0}VV @V{p}VV \\
F_1 \times I @>{u'}>> B \end{CD}
Here $i$ denotes inclusion and $u'(x,t) = u(1-t)$. There exists a lift $H : F_1 \times I \to E$ of $u'$. This is what are looking for.